# The name of Norway do not appear on the map when using geom_text function of ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-text

## The needed libraries

```
library(tidyverse)
library(eurostat)
library(rnaturalearth)
library(rnaturalearthdata)
```

## Loading the map data

```
eurasia <- ne_countries(scale = 50, 
                                                type = "countries", 
                                                continent = c("Europe", "Asia"),
                                                country = NULL, 
                                                geounit = NULL, 
                                                sovereignty = NULL,
                                                returnclass = c("sf")) %>% 
    select(name, iso_a2, continent, subregion, geometry) %>% 
    mutate(iso_a2 = fct_recode(iso_a2, "UK" = "GB", "EL" = "GR"),
                 name = fct_recode(name, "Czechia" = "Czech Rep.",
                                                    "North Macedonia" = "Macedonia",
                                                    "Norway" = "Norway"))
```

## Loading the EUROSTAT data

```
teicp070 <- get_eurostat("teicp070", type = "label", time_format = "date") %>% 
    mutate_if(is_character, as_factor) %>% 
    mutate(geo = fct_recode(
        geo, "Germany" = "Germany (until 1990 former territory of the FRG)", 
        "Turkey" = "Türkiye"))
```

## Summarizing the data and plotting the map

```
prices <- teicp070 %>% 
    filter(unit == "Percentage change m/m-1") %>% 
    group_by(geo) %>% 
    summarise(sm = sum(values)) %>% 
    mutate_if(is.numeric, round, 1)
df <- eurasia %>% 
    inner_join(prices, by = c("name" = "geo"))
df %>% 
    ggplot() +
    geom_sf(aes(fill = sm), alpha = 0.4) +
    coord_sf(xlim = c(-25, 40), ylim = c(34, 72), expand = FALSE) + 
    geom_sf_text(aes(label = name), size = 3.5) + 
    scale_fill_distiller(palette = "Spectral") +
    labs(x = NULL, y = NULL, fill = "%", title = NULL) +
    theme(text = element_text(size = 16), legend.position = "none")
```

This is the whole code I'm running but still can't make the Norway to show up on the map. If anyone could help, I'd be greatful. Thanks!

Comment: To see the label remove `coord_sf`, The issue is that geom_sf_text does not place the label in the "mainland", i.e. under the hood `geom_sf_text` will compute the centroid of a region/polygon to place the label. From the figure It looks that Norway is composed of three polygons and only one is taken into account in this calculation. Nut unfortunately the wrong one. Simple fix would be to add the label for Norway manually.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It seems that it'll work out. I just expanded the top latitude to 82 degrees and now it's okay. Thanks once more! :)